# Why reCaptcha considers everything from a logged in Chrome as authentic?

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I enabled reCaptcha v2 invisible ("most secure" option of slider) on a site and noticed in my tests that basically a challenge is shown  to me if:

- I use any browser other than Chrome
- I use chrome with private
  navigation

I easily created a Selenium test that runs in logged in Chrome, and a challenge is never shown no matter how many times or speed I run the test. So, basically recaptcha v2 invisible is useless against a Selenium "bot" as long as you are logged in to Chrome.

Am I missing something here, or recaptcha is just this dumb?